# Swift average of items in database

Tags: arrays, swift, average

I am trying to calculate the average daily rating for workouts in my app. my results keeps coming back as NaN. My data base shows that there are ratings in there. Here is my average rating function

```
  extension Appointment {
  func averageReview() -> Double {
    guard let workouts = workouts?.allObjects as? [Workout] else {
        return 0
    }
    let total = Double(workouts.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.review})
    let results = Double(total) / Double(workouts.count)
    return results
}

}
```

Comment: Have you double-checked that workouts.count is not zero?

Comment: Yes, there are values

Comment: Please add `print(total, workouts.count)` to your code and show us the output. – Most probably, `nan` is the result of dividing 0.0 by 0.0.

Comment: the print out gave me
0.0, 0, 
3.0, 1,
0.0, 0,
0.0, 0,
0.0, 0,
4.0, 1,
0.0, 1,

Comment: ok , so how do i workout around this. Because i am trying to add up all the reviews and then divide that by the number of workouts

Comment: *You* have to figure out why the array is empty. The above code is correct, but an empty array has no average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dividing by `workouts.count` without making sure it's not equal to zero.

```
extension Appointment {
     func averageReview() -> Double {
         guard let workouts = workouts?.allObjects as? [Workout], workouts.count > 0 else {
             return 0
         }
         let total = Double(workouts.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.review})
         let results = Double(total) / Double(workouts.count)
         return results
     }

}
```